# Extract the detected the approximate shape and bounding box Mask RCNN

Tags: python, opencv, machine-learning, deep-learning, computer-vision

The RCNN Mask detect person add the bounding box and a shape approximation, my aim is to obtain only these
How I can obtain only the shape approximation and the bounding box from RCNN Mask ?

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you have a list of NumPy arrays with objects masks, you can try scikit-image's `regionprops` function, which returns a list of corresponding bounding boxes (and other useful properties as well):

```
from skimage import measure
a = np.array([[0,0,0],[0,1,0],[0,1,0],[0,1,0],[0,0,0]])
b = measure.regionprops(a)
print(b[0].bbox)
```

Returns: `(1, 1, 4, 2)`, which corresponds to `(min_row, min_col, max_row, max_col)`. Note that as according to https://scikit-image.org/docs/dev/api/skimage.measure.html#regionprops , the intervals for bounding box coordinates are half-open (front-inclusive, back-exclusive) as follows: `[min_row; max_row)` and `[min_col; max_col)`.